# My code is not inserting custom object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working with PDO, I want to insert using the feature where you can provide a custom object/class as the parameters for the isnert. No error is thrown in the catch block. If I try to just raw insert entering the fields from the table then it works fine.

Here is my custom class that i want to create an instance of and then insert using PDO

```
class User {
    public $email;
    public $username;
    public $fname;
    public $sname;

    function __construct($e,$u,$fn,$sn) {
        $this->email = $e;
        $this->username = $u;
        $this->fname = $fn;
        $this->sname = $sn;
    }

}
```

Here is the code I use to try and insert

```
try{
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", "myuser", "mypass");
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $user = new User('the email','the username','the fname','the sname');

    $STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO User (email, username, fname, sname) value (:email, :username, :fname, :sname)");
    $STH->execute((array)$user);

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: what does this code do: "(array)$user"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to bind the values first and only then call execute. http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

#### Example

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO User (email, username, fname, sname) value (:email, :username, :fname, :sname)");
$STH->bindParam(':email', $user->email);
// and so on
$STH->execute();
```